# PHP str_replace with for loop from array

Tags: php, arrays, replace, loops, for-loop

Ok I have a str_replace and what I want to do, is take values from an array, and take the next piece to replace the word "dog" with. So basically I want the $string to read:

"The duck ate the cat and the pig ate the chimp"

```
<?php
$string = 'The dog ate the cat and the dog ate the chimp';
$array = array('duck','pig');
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++) {
    $string = str_replace("dog",$array[$i],$string);
}
echo $string;
?>
```

This code just returns:

"The duck ate the cat and the duck ate the chimp"

I tried several things but nothing works. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You could use a combination of `strstr` and `substr_replace` I guess.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** Sorry for the erroneous answer earlier. This'll do it. No `str_replace`, no `preg_replace`, just raw, fast string searching and splicing:

```
<?php
$string = 'The dog ate the cat and the dog ate the chimp';
$array = array('duck', 'pig');
$count = count($array);
$search = 'dog';
$searchlen = strlen($search);
$newstring = '';
$offset = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if (($pos = strpos($string, $search, $offset)) !== false){
        $newstring .= substr($string, $offset, $pos-$offset) . $array[$i];
        $offset = $pos + $searchlen;
    }
}
$newstring .= substr($string, $offset);
echo $newstring;
?>
```

p.s. Not a big deal in this example, but you should keep `count()` outside your loop. With it where you had it, it gets executed every iteration and is slower than just calling it once beforehand.

Comment: The 4th parameter to str_replace has to be a variable and it will be populated with the number of times a replacement happened. Not what you want.

Comment: i replaced str_replace with preg_replace because that uses limit, and now i get "The duck ate the cat and the dog ate the chimp". its not replacing the second "dog" =[

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$string = 'The dog ate the cat and the dog ate the chimp';
$array = array('duck', 'pig');

$count = count($array);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $string = preg_replace('/dog/', $array[$i], $string, 1);
}

echo $string;
?>
```

The duck ate the cat and the pig ate the chimp

Comment: Oh I think I get it, if you keep the same variable "$string" throughout all the statements it will work I assume?

Comment: It'll work. First loop $str = The duck ate the cat and the dog ate the chimp. Second loop The duck ate the cat and the pig ate the chimp.

Answer (score 1):

After the first iteration of your for loop $string will have replaced both occurences of dog with duck and the following iterations will do nothing.

I can't think of a more elegant way of solving this and I hope there is something simpler possible:

```
<?php

$search = 'The dog ate the cat and the dog ate the chimp';
$replacements = array('duck','pig');
$matchCount = 0;
$replace = 'dog';

while(false !== strpos($search, $replace))
{
  $replacement = $replacements[$matchCount % count($replacements)];
  $search = preg_replace('/('.$replace.')/', $replacement, $search, 1);
  $matchCount++;
}

echo $search;
```

Comment: Wow hey at least it works, I'll go over this tonight so I understand it fully. =] thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

yet one option

```
 $str = 'The dog ate the cat and the dog ate the chimp';
 $rep = array('duck','pig');
 echo preg_replace('/dog/e', 'array_shift($rep)', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `substr_replace()`;

```
<?php
function str_replace_once($needle, $replace, $subject)
{
    $pos = strpos($subject, $needle);
    if ($pos !== false)
        $subject = substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($needle));
    return $subject;
}

$subject = 'The dog ate the cat and the dog ate the chimp';
$subject = str_replace_once('dog', 'duck', $subject);
$subject = str_replace_once('dog', 'pig', $subject);

echo $subject;
?>
```