# str_replace - how to handle special circumstances?

Tags: php, str-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP str_replace with for loop from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733375/php-str-replace-with-for-loop-from-array)

How to replace a string (#stringA#) with elements from an array?... let's say we've a text:

`'My shoes are #stringA# but #stringA#'` (the same string - #stringA#)

with $array:

```
$array[0] = 'comfy';
$array[1] = 'smells horrible';
```

so it'll be equal to `'My shoes are ' . $array[0] . ' but ' . $array[1];` - My shoes are comfy but smells horrible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in cases like this, you'd use %s as the string replacement and then use `vsprtinf()` to replace the occurances of %s with values from an array. However, in a simple case like yours, you can also just replace the search strings with %s and achieve the same effect. For example:

```
<?php

$string = 'My shoes are #stringA# but #stringA#';
$key = "#stringA#";

$array[0] = 'comfy';
$array[1] = 'smells horrible';

$string = str_replace(array('%', $key), array('%%', '%s'), $string);
$newstring = vsprintf($string, $array);

echo $newstring;

?>
```

(The replacement of % to %% is to avoid any problems with printf symbols in general case)